# Delay before running vim command?

Tags: autocmd, macvim, startup

This is probably just a bandaid for a greater problem, but I had the following code for MacVim (GUI mode) in my `.vimrc`

```
autocmd GUIEnter * winpos 100 50
```

The problem is it's not working properly on startup, yet if I run `winpos` even 1 second after it starts it works perfect.

The `GUIEnter` command seems to be correct from all I read, and it's still doing GUI stuff after this obviously, because it keeps moving the window just a bit from where I want it.

Is it possible as a hacky workaround to let MacVim load completely, wait 200ms and then execute the `winpos` command?

Comment: You can try to use `sleep` ([`:h :sleep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3asleep)) but you said so: the problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: As [`:help GUIEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#GUIEnter) says `It is triggered before VimEnter when using gvim.`, you should give `VimEnter` a try. And maybe also [`FocusGained`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#FocusGained)

Comment: `sleep` wont work because it prevents Vim from loading in the first place like its frozen

Comment: I tried `FocusGained` and `VimEnter` as well but no dice :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In recent vim versions, you can use `timer_start` to delay an operation.  For example, to execute `winpos` 200 milliseconds after vim starts,

```
autocmd VimEnter * call timer_start(200, { tid -> execute('winpos 100 50')})
```

Comment: So awesome, that worked! `8ms` did the trick :)